# Search for specific line of text file, replace up to a certain character

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk

In file `my_file.ini`, I want to modify the line starting with `dataspecs` like so:

replace `dataspecs old_val old stuff blah blah ! blah blah` with

`dataspecs $new_val ! blah blah`, where `new_val` is a bash variable, and everything after the `!` is preserved. Also, I don't know the value of `old_val`.

I don't care whether it's `sed` or `awk` or just bash, I'm just looking for a simple answer that I can understand. I would really appreciate a solution, especially if you could explain what the code of the solution means, for someone who is just learning sed and awk (not the easiest code to look at). Thanks!

Comment: Please try my sed command. It doesn't need to know the value of `old_val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -i.bak "s/^\( *dataspecs \)[^\!]*/\1${new_val} /" my_file.ini
```

PS: I am using inline flag `-i` of sed for inline editing, this will save the modified file.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't know what `old_val` is!

Comment: Great, except can we replace **anything** between `dataspecs` and `!`? There may be more than just one old value, it may be a few values separated by spaces. Again, I should have been more clear to begin with. I will update my post.

Comment: Almost perfect, except can you leave a space before the `!`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this form of sed:

```
sed "s/^\\(dataspecs \\)[^!]*\\( !.*\\)/\\1${new_val}\\2/" my_file.ini
```

Add `-i` option if you want to modify the file directly.

```
sed -i "s/^\\(dataspecs \\)[^!]*\\( !.*\\)/\\1${new_val}\\2/" my_file.ini
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I understand the basic sed structure `sed -i s///`, but could you please explain what is going on with the parentheses, the \\, and the 2?

Comment: In basic format of it, it's `'s/^\(dataspecs \)[^!]*\( !.*\)/\1new_value\2/'` but we have to quote some parts of it for `""`. All matches of `\(x\)` and `\(y\)` have their place in the replacement string by `\1` and `\2` so anything that they could match would be placed there. It's similar to using `&` which would replace all matches.

Comment: The error is related to history expansion. It only applies when you're interactive in bash, but not in the script. You can disable it temporarily with `shopt -u -o histexpand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/dataspecs old_val/ {$2="$new_val"}1' my_file.ini
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't know what `old_val` is!

Comment: Then its just `awk '/dataspecs/ {$2="$new_val"}1' my_file.ini`