# Replace 5th and 6th "word" in line of text file with bash variable

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-processing

This question expands upon my last question ([Search for specific line of text file, replace up to a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18786352/2707512)). With help from user @anubhava I was able to search for the line starting with dataspecs, and transform it from

`dataspecs  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 ! blah` to

`dataspecs  $new_val ! blah`

However, I now need to be able to keep the variables `v1` `v2` `v3` (I don't know their actual values), and replace `v4` and `v5` with bash variables `$new_v4` and `$new_v5`. So my new line will now look like this:

`dataspecs  v1 v2 v3 new_v4 new_v5 ! blah`

Comment: I think I either need `sed` to (1) tell sed to find the 1st instance of `dataspecs`, assign each word in the line a number, and do subs on "words" 6 and 7, or (2) tell sed to find the 1st instance of `dataspecs` and the 4th instance of whitespace and sub everything in between the whitespace and the `!`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -v n4="$new4" -v n5="$new5" '/^dataspecs/{$5=n4;$6=n5}7' file
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, but where do I tell it to only do subs on the line starting with `dataspecs`? And can you tell me what the `7` does?

Comment: Dataspecs I thought it was a normal string like foobar

Comment: Yeah, it's a normal string, but can you add in your code for the substitutions to only occur on the line starting with `dataspecs`? The file has many other lines.

Comment: One more thing @Kent, I found out there are **two** whitespace characters between `dataspecs` and `v1`. The current code changes this to one whitespace character. How can I keep this as two?

Comment: Preserving whitespace in Awk is less trivial. You could track down the index of each field, but that complicates the script quite a bit.

Comment: If you know the second field will always have extra whitespace, you could do `$2=" " $2` to add a leading space.

Comment: That'll do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Kent's solution is great. Here's another option that involves directly accessing shell variables from within `awk`

```
awk '/^dataspecs/{$5=ENVIRON["new_v4"];$6=ENVIRON["new_v5"];}{print}' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: This solution just replaced the two variables with whitespace for some reason.

Comment: @brastein,  note that the shell variables need to be exported first

Comment: How is that done? Kent's solution seemed to take them from bash, no problem.... Also, I just found out there are **two** whitespace characters between `dataspecs` and `v1`. Do you know how can I keep this as two instead of it changing to one, as Kent's solution does?

Comment: You need to `export` the variables in Bash in order for them to be present in Awk's `ENVIRON` variable.